# Updating UI in WPF project after calling WCF service async

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm, asynchronous

I have a following problem.

```
client.GetServiceMapCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                this.MyServiceMap = e.Result;

                this.MyServiceMap.Categories.Add(new Category() { Name = " " });
                this.MyServiceMap.Groups.Add(new Group() { Name = " " });

                this.MyServiceMap.Groups.Sort((a, b) =>
                    {
                    return String.Compare(a.Name, b.Name);
                    });
                this.MyServiceMap.Categories.Sort((a, b) =>
                    {
                        return String.Compare(a.Name, b.Name);
                    });

                this._parents = MyServiceMap.Nodes;
                this._children = MyServiceMap.Nodes;
            };

        client.GetServiceMapAsync();
```

I have MyServiceMap, Parents and Children properties:

```
    private ServiceMap _serviceMap;
    public ServiceMap MyServiceMap
    {
        get
        {
            return _serviceMap;
        }
        set
        {
            _serviceMap = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyServiceMap");
        }
    }

    private List<Node> _parents;
    public List<Node> Parents
    {
        get
        {
            return _parents;
        }
        set
        {
            _parents = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Parents");
        }
    }

    private List<Node> _children;
    public List<Node> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return _children;
        }
        set
        {
            _children = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Children");
        }
    }
```

In UI i bind MyServiceMap to datagrid, Children and Parents to a listbox.

In a datagrid i see everything as supposed, but children and parents listbox field remains empty.

My question is why my UI is not refreshed after async calling and how to solve that?

Tnx in advanced :)

Comment: Could you provide a minimalistic xaml and how you set the datacontext of your layout?

Comment: in this.loaded event of mainpage.xaml.xs i set the datacontext to view model. 

i bind items source to Parents and children. 

When i don't use async, i can see the list :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the fields and not the properties (where you raise the `PropertyChanged`) so your UI does not get notified about changes.

```
this._parents = MyServiceMap.Nodes;
this._children = MyServiceMap.Nodes;
```

should be

```
Parents = MyServiceMap.Nodes;
Children = MyServiceMap.Nodes;
```

Comment: Tnx. I am looking at that code and wondering why. Omg shame :D